# Is the new full text search in Google app engine multitenancy?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, multi-tenant

I would like to know if the documents for indexing and searching data you have to build are valid for all namespaces or you need one for each namespace.

Comment: view at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy

Answer (score 4):

Yes - the Search API allows you to optionally specify a namespace for an index.  In Python, you would specify the namespace along these lines:
`search.Index(name="myindex", namespace="mynamespace)`.

So, search index multitenancy is supported, analogously to how namespaces in the Datastore support multitenancy.

However, Search index namespaces are not tied to Datastore namespaces.

Comment: Of course you often won't explicitly specify the namespace of an Index, but instead rely on the default behavior which is to get the Index from the current namespace as defined by the namespace_manager.

Comment: I have used namespaces to define different types of data that is from the same source